# What do you call the individual "rounds" you pay in a slot machine?

Tags: word-request

I searched for "[games of slot machines](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22games%20of%20slot%20machines%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq8-Dk1JPYAhWFpJQKHRPeDCMQ_AUIDigA&biw=1855&bih=941)" and "[rounds of slot machines](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=941&tbm=bks&ei=_sE3Wqy8K8Pd0ASrx73QDA&q=%22%20rounds%20of%20slot%20machines%22&oq=%22%20rounds%20of%20slot%20machines%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...89266.92632.0.92769.19.16.0.0.0.0.133.1404.11j4.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..8.0.0....0.419r8EJIcTs)." However these phrases can be easily mistaken for other meanings.

What's the correct way of saying an individual game (one game = pay one time)?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the Wikipedia article for slot machines, it seems that the term *round* is used in the context that you are asking about, whereas *games* appears to mean the types of game that various machines offer. Also, the Wikipedia article and other sites always talk about *bonus rounds*, but never *bonus games*.

[Wikipedia: Slot machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_machine#Terminology)

Comment: So you'd say "Five rounds of slot machines"?

Comment: The usual preposition is *on*.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the individual attempt on a slot machine a **pull**.

> You've earned five free pulls.

Comment: So you'd say "Five pulls of slot machines"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to say with "of slot machines". You could say "five pulls on the slot machine".